# Calculating the area of $\sqrt[2]{x}$ by Riemann sum

Tags: calculus, integration

I'm studying differential and integral calculus, in specific the fundamental theorem. I read that using this, we can calculate the area under functions like $\sqrt[2]{x}=f(x)$ over $[1,9]$ without problem, but I was trying to do it using the Riemann sum, and got stuck right in the beginning. I would appreciate if someone could help. Have a nice day.

I divided the interval $[1,9]$ in $n$ parts, with $x_0 = 1, x_1=1+\Delta x,..,x_n=1+n\Delta x$ and $x_n =9$ which gives $\Delta x = 8/n$. The value of $f(x)$ in some $x_{i-1}$ being $f(x_i)=\sqrt[2]{1+(i-1)\Delta x}$. So, the total area it's just the limit $\lim_{n->+\infty} \sum_{i=0}^{n} (\sqrt[2]{1+(i-1)\Delta x} {\Delta x})$. How do I "solve" the sum for calculating the limit after?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your proposed solution, all of your rectangles have the same width. The key is to let the width of the rectangles vary which will make the summation significantly easier.

Let $x_i = \frac{i^2}{n^2}$ for all $n \leq i \leq 3n$. Notice that $f(x_n) = 1$ and $f(x_{3n}) = 9$. Then $$\Delta x_i = x_{i+1} - x_i= \frac{(i+1)^2}{n^2} - \frac{(i)^2}{n^2} = \frac{2i + 1}{n^2}.$$

Then the (left) Riemann integral becomes $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = n}^{3n -1} f(x_i) \Delta x_i = \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i = n}^{3n-1} \frac{i}{n} \frac{2i + 1}{n^2},$$ which you can calculate using the standard formula $$\sum_{i = 1}^n i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}.$$

I will remark that of all the rectangle widths, the largest is $\Delta x_{(3n-1)}$, where we have $$\Delta x_{(3n-1)}=\frac{(3n)^2 - (3n-1)^2}{n^2} \to 0,$$ as $n \to \infty$. Thus all the widths of the rectangles are becoming arbitrarily small.

Comment: Thank you, it helped a lot.